# Was "SD Art of Fighting" ever released?

Tags: snes, gaming-history

[*Electronic Gaming Monthly #45*](https://archive.org/details/Electronic_Gaming_Monthly_45/page/n71/mode/1up?view=theater) and *Super Play #21* both announced "SD Art of Fighting" as an upcoming Super Famicom game. Was it ever released under another name, or did it get canceled?

[image: SD Art of Fighting]

Comment: ... ***April*** 1993... this does not bode well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This Super Famicom game was actually released as **SD Hiryū no Ken**, part of the *Flying Dragon* franchise. The header of the snippet confirms this with the name of the studio that produced it (Culture Brain).

It got mistakenly translated as an Art of Fighting title because the two series have similar names in Japanese:

- 飛龍の拳 (Hiryū no Ken)
- 龍虎の拳 (Ryūko no Ken)

This mistake also happened to the N64 "[Flying Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Dragon)" game. IGN wrongly reported it as an Art of Fighting title more than once:

- https://www.ign.com/articles/1997/05/01/first-shot-art-of-fighting-twin
- https://www.ign.com/articles/1997/09/10/tgs-two-faces-of-art-of-fighting